# Precise Input Size and Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, input, complexity-theory, time-complexity, computation-theory

When talking about time complexity we usually use *n* as input, which is not a precise measure of the actual input size.  I am having trouble showing that, when using specific size for input (*s*) an algorithm remains in the same complexity class.

For instance, take a simple Sequential Search algorithm.  In its worst case it takes W(n) time.  If we apply specific input size (in base 2), the order should be W(lg L), where L is the largest integer.

**How do I show that Sequential Search, or any algorithm, remains the same complexity class, in this case linear time?**  I understand that there is some sort of substitution that needs to take place, but I am shaky on how to come to the conclusion.

**EDIT**

I think I may have found what I was looking for, but I'm not entirely sure.

If you define worst case time complexity as W(s), the maximum number of steps done by an algorithm for an input size of s, then by definition of input *size*, s = lg n, where n is the input.  Then, n = 2^s, leading to the conclusion that the time complexity is W(2^s), an exponential complexity.  Therefore, the algorithm's performance with binary encoding is exponential, not linear as it is in terms of magnitude.

Comment: So what you're saying is that `O(n) == O(log2(n)^2)`. That's just basic math.

Comment: I guess...I'm just confused now.  The algorithm book I have sucks

Comment: Actually `O(log2(n)^2)` is wrong. I meant `O(2^log2(n))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I know is that the maximum number
>   of steps done by Sequential Search is,
>   obviously, cn^2 + nlg L. cn^2 being
>   the number of steps to increment loops
>   and do branching.

That's not true at all. The maximum number of steps done by a sequential search is going to be c*n, where n is the number of items in the list and c is some constant. That's the worst case.  There is no n^2 component or logarithmic component.

For example, a simple sequential search would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumItems; ++i)
{
    if (Items[i] == query)
        return i;
}
return -1;
```

With that algorithm, if you search for each item, then half of the searches will require fewer than `NumItems/2` iterations and half of the searches will require `NumItems/2` or more iterations. If an item you search for isn't in the list, it will require `NumItems` iterations to determine that. The worst case running time is `NumItems` iterations. The average case is `NumItems/2` iterations.

The actual number of operations performed is some constant, `C`, multiplied by the number of iterations. On average it's `C*NumItems/2`.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with proving that the complexity of the algorithm remains the same with a different encoding for an input.

Comment: @Trevor: Then I (and, it appears, everybody else) misunderstood your question. Perhaps you should find a way to ask it more clearly. Nevertheless, your assertion that the number of steps is somehow related to n^2 is incorrect, regardless of what number base you're using.

Answer (score 4):

> When talking about time complexity we usually use n as input, which is not a precise measure of the actual input size. I am having trouble showing that, when using specific size for input (s) an algorithm remains in the same complexity class.
>
> For instance, take a simple Sequential Search algorithm. In its worst case it takes W(n) time. If we apply specific input size (in base 2), the order should be W(lg L), where L is the largest integer.

*L* is a variable that represents the largest integer.
*n* is a variable that represents the size of the input.
*L* is not a specific value anymore than *n* is.

When you apply a specific value, you aren't talking about a complexity class anymore, you are talking about an instance of that class.

Let's say you are searching a list of 500 integers. In other words, *n* = 500

The worst-case complexity class of Sequential Search is *O(n)*

The complexity is *n*

The specific instance of worst-case complexity is 500

---

Edit:

Your values will be uniform in the number of bits required to encode each value. If the input is a list of 32bit integers, then c = 32, the number of bits per integer. Complexity would be 32*n => O(n).

In terms of L, if L is the largest value, and lg L is the number of bits required to encode L, then lg L is the constant c. Your complexity in terms of bits is O(n) = c*n, where c = lg L is the constant specific input size.

Comment: I'm not asking about a specific instance, I'm asking about precise INPUT size. The input of the algorithm could be 500, but inside a computer things work in binary. Therefore, 500 would be the magnitude of the input and size would be lg (500), the number of bits it takes to encode 500.

Answer (score 1):

As Lucia Moura states: *"Except for the unary encoding, all the other encodings for natural
numbers have lengths that are polynomially related"*

[Here](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/4105-02/np.pdf) is the source. Take a look at page 19.